# XNA 4.0 contentloadexception was unhandled

Tags: xna-4.0

This is my first time doing an XNA project.

I've been following a tutorial (http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/using-3d-models), and I'm having trouble running the game, returning the error in question.

I've read up some similar questions here, as well as on the net, and they almost always have something to do with the content project, root, custom content manager, etc. Now, I'm not really familiar with any of those, as I modified nothing of the XNA's template code, I just added some (from the tutorial).

[image: File in question]

And here's the code:

```
    public class mainClass : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        // Below: Added as of 5/2/13 - referenced from tutorial
        private Model testModel;
        private Matrix testWorld = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        private Matrix testView = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitY);
        private Matrix testProjection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), 800f / 480f, 0.1f, 100f);
        // Code ends here

        public mainClass()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            testModel = Content.Load<Model>("Models/g01-12-13.fbx");
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);            
        }
    }
```

It errors on the testModel Content Load part. Says it can't find the model. I've tried putting it outside the folder, to no avail. Can I have some help on this? Thanks.

P.S. I'm using XNA 4.0, Visual Studio 2010, and Windows 8 (ugh).

Comment: offtopic sidenote: you might wanna consider sharpdx http://sharpdx.org/ which has almost the same api as xna, which is not developed further anymore.

Comment: Is XNA really abandoneware? I mean, developing for it is a no-no now?

Comment: afaik there havent been any updates to XNA since 2009.

Comment: Judging by the lack of answers here, that's possible. Sad, in a way; in my limited experience, as I tried XNA 1.0, it did have a lot of community support, unmatched by, say, jMonkeyEngine (which I also tried).

Comment: again, at the moment i can recommend sharpdx.org . it covers more platforms than xna and it's high-level api is almost identical.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. From what I've downloaded though, I gather using it isn't as simple as XNA.

Comment: MonoGame is an open source version of XNA, and that is being supported.